# How to Check the CheckEdit from Access Database?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, devexpress

I have checkedit in the form. When i click button it get all values from Access Database and fill in the fields in that Form. CheckEdit is available in the form and in the Database Yes/No type datatype is used. Now I want to Check the CHeckEdit if Check is available in Access Database ? How to complete my Task ?

Comment: Expand on your question please, provide some code at the point you are stuck at.

Comment: I have Text Fields in the Form. I store that form in Access Database and Shown in Another Form Gridview. Now i want to edit that, So if i click on any Row in Gridview, according to ID it get values from Access Database and shown in that Previous Form in Same Fields. Till the task work fine, now i have checkedit in the form and i stored in access in "Yes/No" datatype and now if click edit want to get that bool field and show in form as checked/unchecked according to value in Access database. `textEdit1.Text = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();`  like this i get string values & how to get Bool type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved by this code

```
Gender.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(1);
```